# How do I receive ATV with GNU Radio?

Tags: software-defined-radio, gnuradio, atv

How do I receive [Amateur television (ATV)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amateur_television) — e.g., NTSC in the U.S. — with [GNU Radio](http://gnuradio.org/) so I can play the A/V in, e.g., the [VLC video player](https://videolan.org/)? Are there any example GNU Radio block diagrams to accomplish such a task?

<sup>cf. this for an example on [how to decode ATSC with GNU Radio and play the video in VLC](https://coolsdrstuff.blogspot.com/2015/09/watching-atsc-hdtv-on-sdrplay-rsp.html?m=1)</sup>

Comment: I'd like to comment on the article you link to: it's confused about a lot of core concepts of GNU Radio. I wouldn't recommend it as literature for a beginner - as it simply contains statements on what GNU Radio is that are incorrect. I recommend reading the first chapter,the introduction, of the guided GNU Radio tutorials on http://tutorials.gnuradio.org . It especially has a very complicated way of getting data from the SDR device into GNU Radio - in fact, with the osmocom source, one can directly connect one's SDR hardware to the signal processing flow graph. No need to complicatedly record.

Comment: NTSC is all but gone in the US.  The standard now is ATSC.  Years ago someone had come up with an ATSC package.  I'm pretty sure a DVB-T (by now T2) package is out there too.  If you don't get a good answer I will research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends of what signal do you want to receive: ATSC and DVB are digital standards and you have blocks and scripts to deal with as you have seen in the webpage you linked.

DVB has a lot of different modulation and encoding possibilities and dealing with this in GNURadio is a bit of a headache if you do not know the exact parameters to begin with. You can also try [LeanDVB](http://www.pabr.org/radio/leandvb/leandvb.en.html)

Analog television is a totally different beast and I don't know yet how to deal with it. IIRC, the next version of GNURadio has a MJPEG sink on the wishlist to help deal with analog TV signals.

Using RTL receivers you can try a windows only software: [tvsharp](http://www.rtl-sdr.com/analogue-tv-with-rtl-sdr/).

Answer (score -2):

You can break this into 2 parts....

1. GNU Radio for USB receive

   2. Freq 14.225-14.230
2. Output Sink as a WAV File

Then With the Wave file - try and understand the Decoding Process. I would try with.

1. Matlab

When you have got this working then - maybe you can put this process into GNU Radio as a custom Python Module.

Comment: OP is asking about NTSC not SSTV

Comment: Sorry you are correct